# Very small javascript is not running on php page

Tags: javascript

I have javascript working in similar pages, but for some reason this one page does not load the JS at all.  It's not that the code isn't working (it's just a few lines), but on my code debugger (using chromes "inspect element" feature) the javacsript isn't even registered as a script.  I suppose there is some issue in where I am placing it.

I have a header included at the top, then put the script immediately, as follows:

```
<? 
/* Include Files *********************/
require_once("common/header.php");
/*************************************/
?>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    ClearSearch(){
        document.getElementById('search_q').value = '';
    }
</script>
```

Lower in the page, I have a button that calls this function onclick:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_search" value="Show All" onclick="javascript:ClearSearch();">
```

When I click the button, not only is the text box not cleared, but the javascript doesn't seem to run at all.  It's as if the script isn't being detected.  Any ideas?

Comment: This will result in a JavaScript error (a `ReferenceError` when `ClearSearch` is attempted to be invoked) before the submit button is even clicked. Reading error messages will improve the speed of fixing bugs and the quality of SO questions.

Comment: An aside (not the reason it wasn't working, which Niklas has already covered): you shouldn't use a `type='submit'` button unless it submits a form. Try using `type='button'`.

Comment: Ah, I appreciate the comment, but actually I wanted that to stay a submit button, because all it does is set the search query text box to "" and then submits the search form (which I found shows all results, accomplishing the "show all" function.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Missing `function` before your function declaration.

```
function ClearSearch(){
    document.getElementById('search_q').value = '';
}
```

Comment: Haha, thanks, you're a genius.  Or....maybe I'm an idiot.  Let's say a little bit of both - thanks again.